# Java multithreading is performing worse than single threaded

Tags: java, multithreading, raytracing

I have been translating the Ray Tracing in One Weekend guide into Java as a personal project and to get better at java. Obviously, Java is slower than C++, so I'm trying to implement multi-threading to improve performance. However, with multi-threading, the code is running slower than it does with a single thread.

I've tried to ensure that each thread is independent of each other (tested via visualvm) so that they aren't waiting.
[Thread Timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1kCT.png)

I'm not completely sure what to make of the results of sampling the memory.

[Memory Heap Histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHhHS.png)

[Per Thread Allocation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Br3fQ.png)

[VisualVM Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5XXZ.png)

The code below is the multi-threaded render function. Essentially, I render the whole image N times with samples/N samples where N is the number of threads. Then, the images are averaged into one final image. Lastly each pixel is printed (this occurs outside of the thread, in main). I have a slightly older version of the code (without the multi-threading) on github if you need extra context. [Java Raytracer](https://github.com/BobcatNoah/java-raytracer)

```
public void multiThreadedRender(final HittableList world, int threads) {
    initialize();
    samplesPerPixel /= threads;
    
    System.out.print("P3\n" + imageWidth + ' ' + imageHeight + "\n255\n");
    Vec3[] finalImage = new Vec3[imageWidth * imageHeight];
    for (int i = 0; i < finalImage.length; i++) {
        finalImage[i] = new Vec3();
    }

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
    List<Future<Vec3[]>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int thread = 0; thread < threads; thread++) {
        HittableList worldCopy = world.createCopy();

        Callable<Vec3[]> renderTask = () -> {
            Vec3[] partialImage = new Vec3[imageWidth * imageHeight];

            for (int j = 0; j < imageHeight; j++) {
                //System.err.print("\rScanlines remaining: " + (imageHeight - j) + ' ');
                //System.err.flush();
                for (int i = 0; i < imageWidth; i++) {
                    Vec3 pixelColor = new Vec3(0,0,0);
                    Vec3 pixelCenter = pixel00Loc
                    .plus(
                        pixelDeltaU.multiply(i)
                    ).plus(
                        pixelDeltaV.multiply(j)  
                    );
                    for (int sample = 0; sample < samplesPerPixel; sample++) {
                        Ray r = getRay(i, j, pixelCenter);
                        pixelColor.plusEquals(rayColor(r, maxDepth, worldCopy));
                    }
                    partialImage[j*imageWidth+i] = pixelColor;
                }
            }
            System.err.print("\rDone.                           \n");
            return partialImage;
        };  
        futures.add(executorService.submit(renderTask));            
    }

    executorService.shutdown();

    try {
        executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // Handle interruption
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     for (Future<Vec3[]> future : futures) {
        try {
            Vec3[] partialImage = future.get();
            for (int i = 0; i < finalImage.length; i++) {
                finalImage[i].plusEquals(partialImage[i]);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            // Handle exceptions
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < finalImage.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(Color.getColor(finalImage[i], samplesPerPixel * threads));
    }
}
```

Lastly, at an image width of 400 pixels and samples per pixel at 128 in single threaded mode, the total render time is about 12 seconds. With multi-threading (run at 4 threads) it takes about 21 seconds. Run on a 16GB M1 Macbook Air.

Why is the multi-threaded code performing worse than the single thread code? How can I fix it?

Multiprocessing works however and cut the render time in half when creating four processes.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-cp", "Documents/Code/java ray tracer/", "Main");
            try {
                processBuilder.redirectOutput(new File(String.format("image%d.ppm", i)));
                Process process = processBuilder.start();
                if (i == 3) {
                    try {
                        process.waitFor();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Total Time (ms): " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but as far as I can tell, you're not splitting the work, so those threads all do the same work. Also, have you checked the cost of `world.createCopy();`

Comment: That is, likely the setup of threads, doing _thread_ times the work (compared to just doing it once), and then combining _thread_ times the work afterwards (compared to having only one result) is where the real cost is.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I'm rendering the same image multiple times at a lower samples per pixel, then combining them together. That's why I divide the samplesPerPixel by the number of threads. The rendering itself is slow. Also, check createCopy for what?
```
Done.                           
Render time (ms): 19787
Done.                           
Render time (ms): 19816
Done.                           
Render time (ms): 19826
Done.                           
Render time (ms): 19867
Total time: 20242
```

Comment: The information you shared is good to have but doesn't seem very useful. Memory related metrics seem to indicate that there is no bottleneck there. Profiling CPU usage would be useful to identify potential performance bottlenecks. And how many cores does your CPU have?

Comment: I believe the m1 mac has 4 efficiency cores and 4 performance cores. Also, I don't think there is much of an overhead. I could be wrong, but the output I posted shows that most of the total time is rendering.

Comment: @aled I wrote a simple implementation of multiprocessing that seems to work. Creating four processes cuts the render time in half. I'll add the code to the original post. I still don't understand why the multithreading isn't working though.

Comment: Since the only thing that scales down is `samplesPerPixel`, are the two lines in that var's for loop (the `getRay(...)` and `pixelColor.plusEquals(...)` calls) the main bottleneck for your processing? That is, do they represent the majority of the work? You're doing everything else N times (in particular, going over each pixel), so you need to make sure that cost is worth it.

Comment: Rough analogy: imagine you're tryig to paint your house, so you hire 4 people to (a) all paint everything except the door frame, and then (b) each paint one side of the door frame. You wouldn't be surprised that takes more time than just one person painting everything. Instead, you should have had each painter paint one side of the house.

Comment: @yshavit The plusEquals calls is the majority of the work about 95%. Also, rayColor is recursive. The reason I went with my current method is because it was suggested in the original guide. 
>Parallelism — Run  copies of your code on  cores with different random seeds. >Average the  runs. This averaging can also be done hierarchically where /2 >pairs can be averaged to get /4 images, and pairs of those can be averaged. >That method of parallelism should extend well into the thousands of cores with >very little coding.

Comment: Interesting! That's the first thing that jumped out to me, but from what you're describing, it does seem like where you'd want the parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

> Lastly, at an image width of 400 pixels and samples per pixel at 128 in single threaded mode, the total render time is about 12 seconds. With multi-threading (run at 4 threads) it takes about 21 seconds. Run on a 16GB M1 Macbook Air.

Something is really wrong that the multi-threaded case takes almost twice as long.  I just tried a whittled down test:

```
int numThreads = 1;
int numJobs = 4;
ExecutorService executorService = executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);
for (int jobC = 0; jobC < numJobs; jobC++) {
    Callable<Void> renderTask = () -> {
        long total = 0;
        for (long i = 0; i < 100000000000L; i++) {
            total += i;
        }
        System.err.print("Done, total = " + total + "\n");
        return null;
    };
    executorService.submit(renderTask);
}
executorService.shutdown();
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
System.out.println("Took " + ( System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
```

With numThreads set to 1, the program took 130 seconds and with 4 it took 36 seconds.  This is my macbook pro running Chrome, etc..

So Java threads work in general (duh).  Here's what to look for in your application to see what's screwing up the parallelism:

- First off, does running the same code with threads = 1 actually run faster?  Try separating the number of jobs from the number of threads.  Does 1 thread running each of the 4 jobs serially really run faster?  Make sure you are comparing apples to apples.
- Although you seem to be doing a copy of the working data, maybe the threads are sharing a complex data structure so what you are seeing is [cache coherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence) conflicts that is killing your performance.  I'd be surprised that it would take twice as long but I guess it's possible.
- As others have mentioned, be careful of `world.createCopy(...)` and other calls that aren't being run in parallel but may take longer than you think.  Same question with the final image generation.  Maybe adding some `println(...)` messages with timestamps around some of these calls to see if one is taking longer than you expect.
- Is there some way that the `getRay(...)` or other shared methods synchronize on common data?  Similar to the cache coherence question.

Hope something in here helps.

Comment: 1. I ran my code with 1 thread and 1 job, it took 8900 ms to render. Then, I ran the code with 1 thread and 4 jobs in sequence. Each job took about 2200 ms, with a total time of about 9200 ms. (As a reminder, each thread rendered the image at 1/4 of of the samples compared to a single job). If I use same amount of samples per pixel, then each job takes around 8900 ms (the same as 1 job, 1 thread).

The world.createCopy takes almost zero time at all (around 4000 nanoseconds).

As for your other questions. I'll look into those when I have time.

Comment: I think I found the issue. It turns out that Math.random isn't thread safe. I'm happy it's fixed, but also kind of disappointed in myself.

Answer (score -1):

The issue turns out to be that Math.random() is not thread safe. I fixed it by replacing Math.random() with ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble()

Comment: It *is* thread-safe, and it says so specifically in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--).

Comment: That’s weird because when I changed my code to use ThreadLocalRandom it fixed it. I literally didn’t change any other part of my code.

Comment: @user207421 It says this in the javadoc “However, if many threads need to generate pseudorandom numbers at a great rate, it may reduce contention for each thread to have its own pseudorandom-number generator.”

Comment: @BobcatNoah That doesn't mean it is not thread-safe, just that its use from multiple threads concurrently can result in performance issues.